# How to pass template function to POSIX threading (pthread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, c++98

I am in trouble with the usage of a template function with POSIX threading.
As a programming language, I am using C++98, and as a threading infrastructure, I am using POSIX threading (`<pthread.h>`).

*My environment does not support the standard threading (`<thread>`)*

Normally, we can pass parameters to pthreads as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * hello(void *input) {
    printf("%s\n", (char *)input);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, hello, "hello world");
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The question is, how can I pass a template function and parameters to pthreads?

Here is the sample template function:

```
#include <pthread.h>

template<class T>
void *hello(T val){
    SampleInterface *interface = &T;
    cout << interface->Message<<endl;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid;
    SampleClass sClass;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, hello, sClass);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

If I use the above usage, I receive two errors:

```
error: no matches converting function 'hello' to type 'void* (*)(void*)'
error: candidates are: template<class T> void* hello(T)
```

Comment: Alternative: Call the templated function from inside the `void * (void *)` function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you mean call in "hello" function? If yes, it does not solve my problem. Eventually, I have to pass T parameter to this function.

Comment: The problem likely stems from the compiler being unable to infer `T` from `pthread_create(&tid, NULL, hello, sClass);`. But the point is moot. `pthread_create` wants a function that takes a `void` pointer and returns a `void` pointer. Give it anything else and you tempt fate.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right for the "The problem likely stems from the compiler being unable to infer" comment. Still, I could not get it regarding how to do it :/

Comment: I don't think I can formally answer this one without running the risk of helping you dig a deeper hole. `hello` needs to look something like `template<class T>
void *hello(void * userp)` and would be called as `pthread_create(&tid, NULL, hello<SampleClass>, &sClass);`, but that requires `hello` to contain some code like `SampleInterface *interface = (T *)userp;` and I'm not sure this is the right decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not calling `hello()` directly, the compiler can't deduce the template parameter for you, so you have to specify the template parameter explicitly.

You also need to change `hello()` to match the signature that `pthread_create()` is expecting (like your non-template example does), unless you type-cast the function at the point where you pass it to `pthread_create()` (which I don't recommend doing, as it is technically *undefined behavior*, but it does work in some compilers).

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

template<class T>
void *hello(void *arg){
    T *val = static_cast<T*>(arg);
    SampleInterface *interface = val;
    cout << interface->Message << endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid;
    SampleClass sClass;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, hello<SampleClass>, &sClass);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef void* (*pthread_callback_t)(void*);

template<class T>
void *hello(T *val){
    SampleInterface *interface = val;
    cout << interface->Message << endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid;
    SampleClass sClass;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, reinterpret_cast<pthread_callback_t>(hello<SampleClass>), &sClass);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you don't really need the template in your example at all, so you can simplify the code a little:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

void *hello(void *arg){
    SampleInterface *interface = static_cast<SampleInterface*>(arg);
    cout << interface->Message << endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid;
    SampleClass sClass;
    SampleInterface *interface = &sClass;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, hello, interface);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef void* (*pthread_callback_t)(void*);

void *hello(SampleInterface *interface){
    cout << interface->Message << endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid;
    SampleClass sClass;
    SampleInterface *interface = &sClass;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, reinterpret_cast<pthread_callback_t>(hello), interface);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "static_cast" came with C++11. So, I can not use this approach (I am using C++98). This approach is good. Let's try.

Comment: "*static_cast came with C++11*" - no, it did not. Most of the C++ style casts exist in C++98, including `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`. C++11 did add a few new casts, but they are specific to `std::shared_ptr`. But, even if you happened to be using a C++98 compiler that doesn't support `static_cast`, you can just use a C style cast instead, eg: `T *val = (T*)arg;`, `SampleInterface *interface = (SampleInterface*)arg;`, `(pthread_callback_t)hello<SampleClass>`, `(pthread_callback_t)hello`, etc.

Comment: For this code part `" pthread_create(&tid, NULL, reinterpret_cast<pthread_callback_t>(hello), interface);"` , I am receiving `"error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)"` error.

Comment: Is `hello()` a **non-static** method of a class?  If so, you can't use a non-static method for a pthread, because of the implicit `this` parameter that non-static methods have. You have to use a static method or a free-standing function, to get rid of the `this` parameter.  However, you can pass a class object's `this` pointer to the `arg` parameter of `pthread_create()` if `hello()` needs access to non-static members.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh, yes, you are right. I forgot to put static keyword. Right now, it works perfectly. Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

struct SampleInterface {
    int Message;
};

struct SampleClass : public SampleInterface {
    SampleClass() {
        Message = 42;
    };
};

template<class T>
void *hello(void* input){
    SampleInterface *interface = (T*) input;
    std::cout << interface->Message << std::endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid;
    SampleClass sClass;
    SampleInterface* pInterface = &sClass; //see  Remy Lebeau's comment why we should not pass sClass directly to pthread create
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, hello<SampleInterface>, (void*) pInterface);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs, try pasting this code sample here
http://cpp.sh/

Comment: When I use `"template<class T>" for "hello"` function as you mentioned,  then my compiler giving `"error: candidates are: template<class T> void* hello(T)"` error.

Comment: @MahmutEFE That error shows you didn't change `hello`'s input argument from `T` to `void*` to match what `pthread_create()` accepts. Look more closely at the examples you have been given.

Comment: @HappyKeyboard you are passing a `SampleClass*` pointer via `void*` where a `SampleInterface*` is expected. That is technically *undefined behavior* due to a type mismatch. The C++ standard only guarantees getting a valid pointer back from `void*` when it is casted to the same type that was casted to `void*`. So, to fix this, you would have to either 1) use `hello<SampleClass>`, 2) cast `&sClass` to `SampleInterface*` before passing it to `hello<SampleInterface>`, or 3) change `hello<SampleInterface>` to cast `input` to `SampleClass*` before casting to `SampleInterface*`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau good point. Im guessing that @Mahmut EFE wants method `hello` only wants to use a pointer to the interface. updating the code accordingly, and citing comment section for credit